# HIVESQL Query Where Statement Assistance

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a query that I am pulling transactions from. I want to be able to pull transactions where my commodity field = A1 and the newvalue field <> A1 for any of the transactions for each individual case number. In other words, I have 2 case numbers with 5 transactions each, one case number has a transaction record of commodity = A1 and newvalue = A1. The other case has a record where commodity = A1 and newvalue= B2, this is the case I would like returned in the query. Keep in mind that the previous case may have that same transaction but it should not be returned because there is a record of newvalue = A1. I have attached an image and the records highlighted in yellow are what I expect my output to be. Below is my current "Where" statement that I need help re-writing. I was also told that I may need a "Group BY" statement which I tried and still pulled the same results. [image]

```
SELECT 
       Allcases.caseno as caseno, Allcases.division_desc as division_desc, Allcases.close_date as close_date, Allcases.week_of as week_of, 
       Allcases.case_type as case_type, 
       a.transactdate as transactdate, a.transacttypeid as transacttypeid, a.userid as userid,
       concat(RTRIM(Usr.fullname), ' <', RTRIM(Usr.EmailAddress), '>') as CR1_CR2_FULLNAME,
       Allcases.commodity as commodity,
       b.oldvalue as oldvalue, b.newvalue as newvalue, changereason as changereason       
FROM   
(
select b.*, sum(case when b.newvalue = 'A1' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by Allcases.caseno) cnt_new_value_A1
from
       dataiku.qca_casedatachange_parquet b 
       INNER JOIN dataiku.qcatransact_parquet a 
              ON b.transactid = a.transactid
       INNER JOIN dataiku.qca_validated_cases_consolidated_parquet Allcases 
              ON a.casedataid = Allcases.casedataid
       INNER JOIN dataiku.set_qca_reclassification_head_parquet h
              ON Allcases.caseno = h.caseno
       INNER JOIN dataiku.qca_user_parquet Usr
              ON a.UserID = Usr.UserID
where 
    b.FieldID = 6
    AND a.transacttypeid IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND Allcases.commodity = 'A1'
)s
where cnt_new_value_A1 = 0
ORDER BY Allcases.caseno, A.transactid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to return cases for which does not exists record with b.newvalue = 'A1' then calculate analytic sum() and use it in the `where`

```
select ...
from
(
select t.*, 
       sum(case when newvalue ='A1' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by case_number) cnt_new_value_A1
  from ...
 where 
      FieldID = 6 --COMMODITY
   AND transacttypeid IN (1, 2, 3)
   AND commodity = 'A1'
)s
where cnt_new_value_A1 = 0 --No A1 in newvalue  per case_number
```

Comment: Still having some issues @leftjoin below is my full code. I updated my original post with my entire code.

Comment: @A.Bran What issues do you have?